# calling priority of polymorphism function with char* argument and bool argument in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The following is the code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(char* ptr) {
  printf("bar(char*) is called\n");
}

void bar(bool ptr) {
  printf("bar(bool) is called\n");
}

int main() {
  const char* str = "abc";
  bar(str);

  return 0;
}
```

When `bar()` is passed a `const char*` parameter, why `bar(bool)` is called?　Shouldn't `bar(char*)` be called?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that there is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `char*` but there is one from `const char*` to `bool`.

Here is an example when `bar(const char*)` is called (note added `const`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(const char* ptr) { printf("bar(const char*) is called\n"); }
void bar(bool ptr) { printf("bar(bool) is called\n"); }

int main()
{
    const char* str = "abc";
    bar(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior by the compiler. `bar(char*)` cannot be called with a `const char *` argument, as that would defeat const-correctness. On the other hand, `bar(bool)` is a valid choice, so that is what gets called. If you had `bar(const char*)` instead of `bar(char*)`, then `bar(const char*)` would of course been preferred over `bar(bool)` for the call `bar(str)`.